# PhpUnit set workspace directory for every test

Tags: php, phpunit

I haven't found any description how to inject external data into TestCases in phpunit. My goal is to set a workspace directory in the xml config file and read the path of that from every class. Now I can solve this only with global variable, which is disgusting:

In bootstrap:

```
global $workspace;
$workspace = __DIR__ . '/../test/WorkSpace/';
```

In the tests:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $workSpace;

    public function __construct()
    {
        global $workspace;
        $this->workSpace = $workspace;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //...
}
```

The config xml for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://phpunit.de/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         verbose="true"
         bootstrap="Application/bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="PHPUnit">
            <directory>test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using globals. For this purpose, you can [define constants](http://php.net/define) in your bootstrap file.

Im reviewing the documentation and I've found that [you can define PHP values in your XML file](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/appendixes.configuration.html).

> **Setting PHP INI settings, Constants and Global Variables**
>
> The  element and its children can be used to configure PHP settings, constants, and global variables. It can also be used to prepend the include_path.

```
<php>
      <includePath>.</includePath>
      <ini name="foo" value="bar"/>
      <const name="foo" value="bar"/>
      <var name="foo" value="bar"/>
      <env name="foo" value="bar"/>
      <post name="foo" value="bar"/>
      <get name="foo" value="bar"/>
      <cookie name="foo" value="bar"/>
      <server name="foo" value="bar"/>
      <files name="foo" value="bar"/>
      <request name="foo" value="bar"/>
    </php>
```

> The XML configuration above corresponds to the following PHP code:

```
ini_set('foo', 'bar');
define('foo', 'bar');
$GLOBALS['foo'] = 'bar';
$_ENV['foo'] = 'bar';
$_POST['foo'] = 'bar';
$_GET['foo'] = 'bar';
$_COOKIE['foo'] = 'bar';
$_SERVER['foo'] = 'bar';
$_FILES['foo'] = 'bar';
$_REQUEST['foo'] = 'bar';
```

As I've said above, I'd recommend you to use constants using define, instead of global variables.

Comment: That's the same for me. Is there any way to define it in the xml file?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check if that suits what you are looking for